# Is it safe to remove Install.php from my Magento 1.9 src folder?

Tags: php, magento, installation, magento-1.9

This is the location of the file

```
magento-website/src/install.php
```

What, if any, would be the repercussions of deleting this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe.

the repercussion would be the lack of possibility to re-install if etc/local.xml somehow disappear